$\lim_{x\to 10}(\sqrt{-(x-10)^2})=0$ or $\lim_{x\to 10}(\sqrt{-(x-10)^2})$ is undefined?
I am reviewing calculus 1 and I saw this problem. The problem is $\lim_{x\to 10}(\sqrt{-(x-10)^2})$. The answer guide says the answer is undefined, since the function is not defined on an open interval at x=10 and is only defined on a single point, $x=10$, at which $\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}=0$. Well I believe that $\lim_{x\to 10}(\sqrt{-(x-10)^2})$ does in fact $=0$, contrary to the answer guide. This is because $\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}$ is actually defined for $x\ne10$, just in the imaginary numbers instead of the real ones. And that the imaginary value of $\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}$ gets closer to zero as x approaches ten. I have shown this using a delta-epsilon proof.
$$((\epsilon>0\;\land\;0<\delta\le\epsilon)\implies$$
$$(\lvert{x-10}\rvert<\delta\implies$$
$$\lvert{i(x-10)}\rvert<\delta\implies$$
$$\lvert{\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}}\rvert<\delta\implies$$
$$\lvert{\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}-0}\rvert<\delta\implies$$
$$\lvert{\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}-0}\rvert<\epsilon))\implies$$
$$(\forall\;\epsilon>0\;\exists\;\delta>0 \text{ s.t }\lvert{x-10}\rvert<\delta\implies\lvert{\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}-0}\rvert<\epsilon)\implies$$
$$\lim_{x\to10}(\sqrt{-(x-10)^2}=0$$
The crucial step of this proof is rewriting $\lvert{x-10}\rvert$ as $\lvert{i(x-10)}\rvert$. As far as I'm aware, the two statements are equivalent because absolute value measures the distance of any complex number to the origin, so in general $\lvert{x}\rvert = \lvert{ix}\rvert$ just as $\lvert{x}\rvert = \lvert{-x}\rvert$. Where is my mistake?


Where is my mistake?

Your mistake is changing the rules of the game. This is a calculus problem; there are no complex numbers. In particular, the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ has a very concrete meaning: for $x\geq0$, it is the unique $z\geq0$ such that $z^2=x$; and for $x<0$ it is not defined. Instead you are choosing to interpret the symbols $\sqrt{x}$ as
$$
\sqrt x=\begin{cases} \sqrt x,&\ x\geq0\\[0.2cm] i\sqrt{-x},&\ x<0\end{cases}
$$
Which is possible, of course, but certainly not what the author meant, and not what is meant in every single calculus text out there.

How am I meant to determine which definition of sqrt is being used?

Or perhaps the definition of sqrt is consistent, but that the definition of the limit isn't consistent. Perhaps the delta-epsilon limit requires that x, a, f(x), and L are all real numbers. It's just confusing because all the definitions I've seen of the delta-epsilon limit don't specify that they all have to be real numbers.

In any math text, $\sqrt x $ means the unique non-negative root of $x$. It's a (very reasonable) convention, the same way that we have a convention that says that $+$ denotes addition.

The definition of limit does not require real numbers. The way you wrote it, it works fine with complex numbers. But you are talking about calculus 1; the same way that "integral" in calculus 1 means a one-variable integral, in calculus 1 functions have real domains, and are real valued. The same way that the phrase "$x^2+1$ has no roots" is perfectly acceptable and correct.

What symbols would be used to denote the definition of sqrt used in my proof? Specifically sqrt(x) when x >= 0 and i*sqrt(-x) when x < 0
would be useful to know

It's just some function, so call it whatever you want. The same way that there is no concrete name for the function that is $\sin x$ for $x\geq0$ and $-\exp(-x ^2)$ when $x<0$, there is no concrete name for the function you want. Things get named when they are used frequently by many.

Okay, I think I see where my confusion is. In school I was taught that i = sqrt(-1), but that seems to be false. Rather, it seems that i is defined as the solution of x^2 = -1. Though that's also confusing because there are two possible solutions for x.

@LaurenS: yes, exactly! That's a good insight. The problem with "the square root of $-1$" lies in the "the", because there are two of them in the complex plane, and you wouldn't know which one to choose. Notwithstanding the fact that first you need to somehow construct the complex plane. So it is more sound to construct an object $i$, such that $i^2=-1$, and go from there. (continued)

(continued) This can be done in several way, like defining $\mathbb C$ to be $\mathbb R^2$ with the multiplication suited to $(0,1)^2=(-1,0)$. Or defining $\mathbb C$ as the $2\times 2$ matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} a&b\-b& a\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad a,b\in\mathbb R$$ with the usual matrix operations. Or defining $\mathbb C=\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.
